# Comment section not showing correctly

Tags: plugins, comments, disqus

I've followed the instructions of all of the comment plugins I've downloaded for example Disqus and Livefyre and they both don't seem to show up correctly, the styling of the comment section isnt showing, it's just displaying the comments as plain text.

I've tried digging for the problem within the settings of the both plugins but they all seem to be correctly set. and all the questions from the forums site I've tried have been about them not enabling their comments which I know I've enabled, due to me seeing the comments in plain text.

after a certain point, I even tried to revert back to the default WordPress comment section to see if its the plugins or just my installation of WordPress, and with no luck, it still didn't style.

I'm using a custom theme that I've built myself, maybe I'm supposed to style the comments myself, but from what I see Disqus comes with its own style that looks the same on all sites that have it installed. I haven't tampered with or tried to style the comments in my custom CSS file they just seem to not work.

The theme I had before I built my custom theme was MH Squared lite and the comments (even though they weren't the best looking) worked perfectly

Just to clarify, the codes that I've already tried are `comments_template()`, `comment_form()`, `the_comment()` and `get_comments()`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I'm really confused and stuck right now